# 'No row at position' when assigning column value to a dataset in c#

Tags: c#, dataset, newrow

I am trying to execute following code. All I am trying to do is to copy one column from a dataset into one of the columns of another dataset. The code is as follows:

```
    int i=0
    foreach (DataRow dr in ds_input.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
     ds_output.Tables["output"].Rows[i]["Serial_Number"] = dr["Serial Number"].ToString();
i++;
    }
```

While assigning column value of `dr` to `ds`, the compiler returns the following error:

`There is no row at position 0.`

Despite making the following addition, it returns the same error:

```
   int i=0;
     foreach (DataRow dr in ds_input.Tables[0].Rows)
     {
         ds_output.Tables["output"].NewRow();
         ds_output.Tables["output"].Rows[i]["Serial_Number"] = dr["Serial Number"].ToString();
     i++;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the `DataRow` to the `DataTable`. If the output- and the input-tables have the same columns you could use [`DataTable.Clone`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone.aspx) to clone the table which does not copy the data. Then you can either use `DataTable.ImportRow` to create a copy of the `DataRow` from the input table and add that to the output-table. Or you could use `table.Rows.Add` to add a new `DataRow` and use the `ItemArray`(all fields) of the input-DataRow:

```
DataSet ds_output = new DataSet();
DataTable tblOutput = ds_input.Tables[0].Clone();
ds_output.Tables.Add(tblOutput);
foreach (DataRow dr in ds_input.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    tblOutput.ImportRow(dr);
    // or:
    DataRow newRow = tblOutput.Rows.Add();
    newRow.ItemArray = dr.ItemArray;
}
```

If you want to create a complete copy of the input-table you can use [`DataTable.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
DataTable tblOutput = ds_input.Tables[0].Copy(); // nothing more needed
```

Comment: Actually, there are 4 columns in output dataset, 1 of which is to be copied from input dataset and rest of the 3 from databases. it would be great if you could give me an example of your second suggestion.

Comment: @Salik: I have given both samples. The second starts in the loop with `//or`. You can modify `newRow` as you wish, you don't need to use `ItemArray` to copy all fields. You can use `newRow.SetField("ColumnName", value)` to set the field's value. Note that `tblOutput.Rows.Add()` does not only return the `DataRow` but that this row is already added to the `DataTable`, so you don't need to add it again later.